# Recommendation Engine using Apache Spark MLIB showing up Zero recommendations after processing all operations

Tags: machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering, machine-learning-model

I am a newbie when it comes to Implementation of ML Algorithms. I wanted to implement a recommendation Engine and Got to know after little experimenting that collaborative-filtering can be used for the same. I am using Apache Spark for the same. I got help from one of the blogs and tried to implement the same in my local. PFB Code that I tried out. Every time I execute this the Count of Recommendations that is getting printed is always zero. I don see any Evident Error as such. Could someone please help me understand this. Also, please feel free to provide any other reference that can be referred in this regard.

```
package mllib.example;

import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating;

import scala.Tuple2;


public class RecommendationEngine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        // Create Java spark context
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Recommendation System Example").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory","1g");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        // Read user-item rating file. format - userId,itemId,rating
        JavaRDD<String> userItemRatingsFile = sc.textFile(args[0]);

        System.out.println("Count is "+userItemRatingsFile.count());

        // Read item description file. format - itemId, itemName, Other Fields,..
        JavaRDD<String> itemDescritpionFile = sc.textFile(args[1]);

        System.out.println("itemDescritpionFile Count is "+itemDescritpionFile.count());

        // Map file to Ratings(user,item,rating) tuples
        JavaRDD<Rating> ratings = userItemRatingsFile.map(new Function<String, Rating>() {
            public Rating call(String s) {
                String[] sarray = s.split(",");
                return new Rating(Integer.parseInt(sarray[0]), Integer
                        .parseInt(sarray[1]), Double.parseDouble(sarray[2]));
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Ratings RDD Object"+ratings.first().toString());

        // Create tuples(itemId,ItemDescription), will be used later to get names of item from itemId
        JavaPairRDD<Integer,String> itemDescritpion = itemDescritpionFile.mapToPair(
                new PairFunction<String, Integer, String>() {
            @Override
            public Tuple2<Integer, String> call(String t) throws Exception {
                String[] s = t.split(",");
                return new Tuple2<Integer,String>(Integer.parseInt(s[0]), s[1]);
            }
        });

        System.out.println("itemDescritpion RDD Object"+ratings.first().toString());

        // Build the recommendation model using ALS

        int rank = 10; // 10 latent factors
        int numIterations = Integer.parseInt(args[2]); // number of iterations

        MatrixFactorizationModel model = ALS.trainImplicit(JavaRDD.toRDD(ratings),
                rank, numIterations);
        //ALS.trainImplicit(arg0, arg1, arg2)

        // Create user-item tuples from ratings
        JavaRDD<Tuple2<Object, Object>> userProducts = ratings
                .map(new Function<Rating, Tuple2<Object, Object>>() {
                    public Tuple2<Object, Object> call(Rating r) {
                        return new Tuple2<Object, Object>(r.user(), r.product());
                    }
                });

        // Calculate the itemIds not rated by a particular user, say user with userId = 1
        JavaRDD<Integer> notRatedByUser = userProducts.filter(new Function<Tuple2<Object,Object>, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(Tuple2<Object, Object> v1) throws Exception {
                if (((Integer) v1._1).intValue() != 0) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }).map(new Function<Tuple2<Object,Object>, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call(Tuple2<Object, Object> v1) throws Exception {
                return (Integer) v1._2;
            }
        });

        // Create user-item tuples for the items that are not rated by user, with user id 1
        JavaRDD<Tuple2<Object, Object>> itemsNotRatedByUser = notRatedByUser
                .map(new Function<Integer, Tuple2<Object, Object>>() {
                    public Tuple2<Object, Object> call(Integer r) {
                        return new Tuple2<Object, Object>(0, r);
                    }
        });

        // Predict the ratings of the items not rated by user for the user
        JavaRDD<Rating> recomondations = model.predict(itemsNotRatedByUser.rdd()).toJavaRDD().distinct();

        // Sort the recommendations by rating in descending order
        recomondations = recomondations.sortBy(new Function<Rating,Double>(){
            @Override
            public Double call(Rating v1) throws Exception {
                return v1.rating();
            }

        }, false, 1);   

        System.out.println("recomondations Total is "+recomondations.count());

        // Get top 10 recommendations
        JavaRDD<Rating> topRecomondations = sc.parallelize(recomondations.take(10));

        // Join top 10 recommendations with item descriptions
        JavaRDD<Tuple2<Rating, String>> recommendedItems = topRecomondations.mapToPair(
                new PairFunction<Rating, Integer, Rating>() {
            @Override
            public Tuple2<Integer, Rating> call(Rating t) throws Exception {
                return new Tuple2<Integer,Rating>(t.product(),t);
            }
        }).join(itemDescritpion).values();

        System.out.println("recommendedItems count is "+recommendedItems.count());

        //Print the top recommendations for user 1.
        recommendedItems.foreach(new VoidFunction<Tuple2<Rating,String>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Tuple2<Rating, String> t) throws Exception {
                System.out.println(t._1.product() + "\t" + t._1.rating() + "\t" + t._2);
            }
        });
```

Also, I see  that this job is Running for real Long time. Every time it creates a model.Is there a way I can Create the Model once, persist it and Load the same for consecutive Predictions. Can we by any chance improve the Speed of execution of this job

Thanks in Advance

Comment: way to much code to go through here.. break this down to the RDD you want to train on, cut out the code not needed for the question, please provide a .take(2) of that RDD with header. Check out `recommendProductsForUsers` method for the ALS model.